# How do I change a variable's value with the command from a Tkinter button?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, label, command

The command I set for a Tkinter button was a function that changed the text of a label. Yet the text does not seem to change!

The variable I attempted to change using the function "textChange()" is called "text", and the purpose of its value is to be the text of a label called "finalText". But, the text of the label "finalText" didn't change!

```
#Imports
from tkinter import *

#Variables
wn = Tk()
text = 'Button Commands'


#Change Text
def textChange():
  global variable
  text = 'Can do THIS!'
  finalText = Label(wn, text=text)


finalText = Label(wn, text=text)
finalText.place(x=0, y=0)

#Button
btn = Button(wn, command=(textChange()))

btn.place(x=5, y=20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually create a new label and assign to a local variable `finalText` inside `textChange()`.  So the global `finalText` is not changed.

You need to use `finalText.config(text=text)` to update the text of the global `finalText`.

Also `command=(textChange())` will execute `textChange()` immediately without clicking the button.  Use `command=textChange` instead.

Below is the updated code:

```py
#Imports
from tkinter import *

#Variables
wn = Tk()
text = 'Button Commands'

#Change Text
def textChange():
    text = 'Can do THIS!'
    # update the text of the global label finalText
    finalText.config(text=text)

finalText = Label(wn, text=text)
finalText.place(x=0, y=0)

#Button
btn = Button(wn, command=textChange)
btn.place(x=5, y=20)

wn.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you!

I think I understand. Instead of changing the value of "finalText", I update it with the "configure" function?